# How to scan integers in double loops. c-language

Tags: for-loop, scanf

I would like to know how to scan integers into two arrays.
My codes is as follow, but it doesn't work.I use C language by the way.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[10]={0};
    int b[10];
    for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
        printf("input b");
        scanf("%d",b[i]);
        for(int j=1;j<=3;j++)
        {
            printf("input a");
            scanf("%d",a[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do and what you mean by "it doesn't work"?  Without clarification, I can only take a guess and say that you probably don't want to have the second for loop inside of the the other one.

Answer (score 0):

scanf requires an address to know where to store the value it reads. You can get the address of a local variable using '&'.

`scanf("%d", &b[i]);`
`scanf("%d", &a[j]);`

You should read up on pointers to understand how they work in C. It's a fair amount to take in but you will become a much better C programmer once you understand it.

These are two guides I found, [Pointers in C](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm) and [The 5-minutes Guide to C Pointers](https://denniskubes.com/2017/01/24/the-5-minute-guide-to-c-pointers).